# Changing variable with loop in VBA mysql query?

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I created a loop in VBA that should change a variable (j) in the strSql portion of the code. My output columns on the excel sheet are all indentical. That means that the changing variable j is not taken into consideration in the strsql string. Does anybody know how to use a proper changing variable in this case? Thanks in advance

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

```
     For j = 1 To 6


    strSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM( " & _
     "SELECT COUNT(*) as nbp FROM `order`   " & _
     "JOIN user ON user.id = order.destination_id   " & _
     "AND DATEDIFF(date_added , register_date) <= j" & _
     "GROUP BY destination_id)  c  " & _
     "GROUP BY nbp " & _
     "ORDER BY c.nbp ASC ; "



    rs.Open strSql, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

    res = rs.GetRows

    rs.Close

    For i = 1 To 2
    Cells(i, j) = res(0, i - 1)
    Next i
    Next j
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move j out of your string

register_date) <= j" &

To

register_date) <= " & j &

Comment: I tried that but I still get an error message. ODCB driver does not support the requested properties. But thnaks

Comment: ODCB driver does not support the requested properties

Comment: Well, that's a completely different issue... answer solves what you asked so I'm upvoting.

Comment: Hmm I dint think that error is related to the use of j, can you extract the string and execute it against the database directly which should indicate wherever statement is failing?

Comment: Everything works fine when I take the j out of the sql string. It is just when I put it in that it dosnt give me the desired results. I did not try the loop within mysql. (because I dont know how). But the statment is fine

Comment: Put a break point on rs.getrows and inspect the strSql variable to get the sql statement and then run that statement directly against the db using whatever ide you have for mysql and report see where it errors

Comment: I found the problem. Your solution works but I need to put an extra space in the next line. j was stuck to group. Thanks alot Rich

Answer (score 2):

Rather nasty but in vba with ado I guess this is quickest hack... You don't necesarly need to convert j to a string but I rather be explicit...

```
strSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM( " & _
     "SELECT COUNT(*) as nbp FROM `order`   " & _
     "JOIN user ON user.id = order.destination_id   " & _
     "AND DATEDIFF(date_added , register_date) <= " & _ 
     CStr(j) & " " & _
     "GROUP BY destination_id)  c  " & _
     "GROUP BY nbp " & _
     "ORDER BY c.nbp ASC ; "
```

Comment: Thanks rene. U still get an error message when I use your methos

Comment: Also you would need to have a space after the CSTR(J) or else the group by won't be recognized...CStr(j) & " " & _
     "GROUP BY destination_id)  c  " & _